Is this question about linear growth or exponential growth?
I am studying Precalculus for the CLEP, which is a standardized test that allows for the granting of college credit at certain schools.
I have the following problem:
"The population of city Z was 420,000 in the year 2000. If the population is projected to grow at a constant rate of 2 percent per year, which of the following is closest to the projected population of city Z in the year 2030?"
This question is presented in a section on linear functions, but it seems to me that it belongs in the section on exponential functions.
If I try to solve it as true constant rate, I get the wrong answer. If I solve it as an exponential function, I get the correct answer which of the choices is 760,000.
Am I just doing it incorrectly in trying to solve it in some linear function way or is the question misplaced and belongs in a section on exponential growth?
Thanks.

This is indeed exponential growth. Let $P(n)$ denote your population at the year $n$ (say we start at $n = 0$). In your case, you can write $P(n) = a^n P(0)$, where $a > 1$ is a constant (what is $a$?), which is by definition, exponential growth.
Linear growth would be something like: "Assume no one is ever born, or ever dies in the city, but a fixed number of $b$ newcomers immigrate to the city each year." Then, you would have $P(n) = P(0) + bn$

I'll comment that probably the reason this question was included in the linear growth section was meant as a trap. To warn students that it's not because the "label", or the "name of the chapter" says something that you should always follow it without question, and that you should rather trust your intuition. (So congrats on passing this test!)
